# responsivness of website for iphone 6

Tags: iphone, css

I have figured out there is problem with media queries which causes the hindrance in the responsiveness of the website on particularly iphone 6 could someone find me a fix for this as i am not able to make it responsive on iphone 6 
website link : www.buildwithcraft.co

Comment: Website link : www.buildwithcraft.co

Answer (score 0):

```
/*iPhone 6 Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) {

}

/*iPhone 6 landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) {

}

/*iPhone 6+ Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) {

}

/*iPhone 6+ landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) {

}

/*iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ portrait and landscape*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
}

/*iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ portrait*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation : portrait) {

}

/*iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ landscape*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation : landscape) {

}
```